# in React, Is it possible to access a class method through a ref, from an asynchronous fetch?

Tags: reactjs, class, methods, parent-child, ref

I have a react component (let's call it Uploader) that contains several methods for uploading files to a server. This component is used in several places of the app and has some peculiar requirements to function. I would like to make its functionality/methods available to a parent component for a particular use case, in which i send text to the server, it stores it and returns the resource's information, including its ID (which the uploader needs to properly upload a file to a resource). Basically i want to be able to attach files to a message, but the server requires certain order of operations.

Create Resource => create fileSlot (where file metadata is stored in dB) => upload files to created resource fileSlot (for which i need the resource ID)

Without the created resource, there is nowhere to store the filedata

So i would like to call the methods of the Uploader from the Parent component, and i am able to make it work at a basic level, such as with an onClick event on a button. For example

```
const Parent = () => {

    const theRef = React.createRef()

    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={()=>theRef.current.test()}>Test Me</button>
            <Uploader ref={theRef}
        </div>
    )
}

class Uploader extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){blabla...}

    test(){
        alert('test worked!')
    }

    render(){
        return (...blabla)
    }

}
```

This is an oversimplified example, but illustrates the proof of concept with which i was able to call a method with the Ref. This works!

However, it no longer works if i try to call it from an asynchronous function such as a fetch. I need to chain this so the file gets uploaded after the message gets created, so that would look something like this

```
const Parent = () => {

    const theRef = React.createRef()

    const handleSendMessage = () => {
        fetch(params).then(json=>{
            //lets assume the response is Ok and has been converted to json()
            if(success){
                //THIS IS WHERE I WANT TO CALL THE METHOD OF THE CHILD COMPONENT WITH THE REF
                //SO IT WILL PERFORM THE FILE UPLOAD, HOWEVER IT TELLS ME THAT THE REF IS NULL

                theRef.current.test()
            }
        })
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={handleSendMessage}>Test Me</button>
            <Uploader ref={theRef}
        </div>
    )
}

class Uploader extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){blabla...}

    test(){
        alert('test worked!')
    }

    render(){
        return (...blabla)
    }

}
```

so that's essentially the problem im having. I've tried doing it through handler functions so it's not directly called from within the "then()" but still it doesnt work. KEep in mind handler functions DO work with the onClick example, but it looks like the fact that it is asynchronous it does not have access to the ref methods or something.

Does anyone know if there is a way to do this?

Comment: Does replacing `const theRef = React.createRef()` with `const theRef = useRef()` work? That hook will guarantee you get the same `theRef` object each time you rerender.

Comment: why not just pass an updated state value, you would set that in the success area. then pass that to the child. let the child when it gets that update call its own method?

Comment: @JohnRuddell i thought of that, the problem is that i also need to pass it the resourceId as well as some value to trigger the method from within the component, and passing two props synchronously might cause two renders, and id rather not make the child component too "tailormade" since i use it in many other places of the app. But i am considering a similar approach as the solution

Comment: @JoshWilson that actually worked! what a wonderful and simple fix! I hadn't even considered using a ref hook instead of the createRef() function!

Comment: well @xunux the resourceId could be the trigger. I would pass what you need to pass via state to the child component, let it get what it needs as props and do what it needs to do when it gets that prop. like in `componentDidUpdate` for instance where you can check to see if the last props didnt have a resourceId or if its changed :)

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: by **Josh Wilson** comment, you need to use **useRef** instead of `createRef`, because there is a probability that ref isn't assigned in time of the function assignment.

```js
class Uploader extends React.Component {
  test() {
    alert('test worked!')
  }

  render() {
    return <div>Uploader</div>
  }
}

const App = () => {
  const theRef = React.useRef()

  const handleSendMessage = () => {
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1').then(json=>{
      theRef.current.test()
    });
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleSendMessage}>Test Me</button>
      <Uploader ref={theRef}/>
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Well, this is odd. Because essentially this illustrates exactly what i was trying to do, however that is not working for me, if it had this question wouldve never existed. I'm not sure why it's working in your example but not in my code, it is essentially the same thing. What fixed it was using the useRef() hook instead of createRef() func

Comment: I didnt downvote either, but i'll say probably the reason why is because your answer is literally the same as the OP's question. So it wont work, otherwise why would the OP have asked the question in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Credit to @joshwilson his fix was the simplest of fixes and it worked. By using the useRef hook instead of the createRef() function this is now working as desired.